# Doctrine EntityRepository for extended Entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am having problem with mapping custom entity repository to Entity which is extended from another entity.

Base entity:

```
/**
 * User entity
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity
 *
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="user_type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"user" = "User", "client" = "Client"})
 */
class User
{
}
```

Extended entity:

```
/**
 * Client entity
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\AppBundle\Entity\ClientRepository")
 */
class Client extends User
{
}
```

Repository:

```
namespace Acme\AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

/**
 * ClientRepository
 */
class ClientRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    /*
     * this method returns resultset
     * its empty just for simplification
     */
    public function getClientsWithActiveCampaign(\DateTimeInterface $date = null) {}
}
```

Calling the repository:

```
$clients = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeAppBundle:Client')->getClientsWithActiveCampaign();
```

But when I am calling custom method on `ClientRepository` I get:

```
Undefined method 'getClientsWithActiveCampaign'. The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy!
```

So it seems that Doctrine doesn't know about my custom repository.

Comment: your repository class must be extended by Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository.

Comment: can you show the call of the repo and the repo head (namespace, uses, class declaration)?

Comment: Just few days ago I had the need for this and had no problems at all. Must be some silly mistake...

Comment: Please, show us how do you get your repository entity.

Comment: post edited - added repository class + call of repository

Comment: Might need to to do the ever popular clearing of the cache.

Comment: @Cerad I am afraid that this is not the issue - I cleared cache by app/console and I also manually removed app/cache content but it is still not working.

Comment: Not sure if this affects it, but the return of from a repository call should be an entity/scalar from a DB query.  Can you add a basic query to ClientRepository and see if the error changes?

Comment: @George my method returns Resultset, I just don't write the body of function for simplification - it's not important. Error occurs in binding, but I don't know where.

Comment: Can you split you code into two lines: `$em= $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();` and `$clients = $em->getRepository('AcmeAppBundle:Client')->getClientsWithActiveCampaign();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thinking about this, the entity manager is missing and that is why it cannot find the repository. In your controller/service, use:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$clients = $em->getRepository('AcmeAppBundle:Client')->getClientsWithActiveCampaign();
```

The `$clients` variable should be populated now, or at least you will get a different error. The `getClientsWithActiveCampaign` function should run.

Comment: I had this before your answer but I forget to delete some legacy code which triggers the error so I think that this is not correct solution. Thanks for your answer.